# Basler pylon ip camera TimoutException thrown (file 'tlfactory.cpp', line 694) in python

Tags: python, ip-camera

I have a problem using Basler Pylon ip camera while grabbing. I set my ip as shown below.
[image: IP address of the ethernet connection]

I used the grab.py code of pypylon from [Github basler/pypylon/grab.py](https://github.com/basler/pypylon/blob/master/samples/grab.py). It works when I tried it on another computer but it throws a timeout exception on my computer. Can you please help me how to solve this problem?

The code:

```
from pypylon import pylon
from pypylon import genicam

import sys

countOfImagesToGrab = 100

exitCode = 0

try:
    camera = pylon.InstantCamera(pylon.TlFactory.GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice())
    camera.Open()

    print("Using device ", camera.GetDeviceInfo().GetModelName())

    new_width = camera.Width.GetValue() - camera.Width.GetInc()
    if new_width >= camera.Width.GetMin():
        camera.Width.SetValue(new_width)

    camera.MaxNumBuffer = 5

    camera.StartGrabbingMax(countOfImagesToGrab)

    while camera.IsGrabbing():
        grabResult = camera.RetrieveResult(5000, pylon.TimeoutHandling_ThrowException)

        if grabResult.GrabSucceeded():
            print("SizeX: ", grabResult.Width)
            print("SizeY: ", grabResult.Height)
            img = grabResult.Array
            print("Gray value of first pixel: ", img[0, 0])
        else:
            print("Error: ", grabResult.ErrorCode, grabResult.ErrorDescription)
        grabResult.Release()
    camera.Close()

except genicam.GenericException as e:
    print("An exception occurred.")
    print(e.GetDescription())
    exitCode = 1

sys.exit(exitCode)
```

**And the error is:** _genicam.TimeoutException: Grab timed out. Possible reasons are: The image transport from the camera device is not working properly, e.g., all GigE network packets for streaming are dropped; The camera uses explicit triggering (see TriggerSelector for more information) and has not been triggered; Single frame acquisition mode is used and one frame has already been acquired; The acquisition has not been started or has been stopped. : TimeoutException thrown (file 'instantcameraimpl.h', line 1037)

[image: TimoutException]

Answer (score 0):

There is a warning in the error section that the camera is triggered explicitly. I guess the `grab` method is triggered in a different way. For this, can you change the `startgrabbingmax` method in your code with `camera.StartGrabbing(pylon.GrabStrategy_LatestImageOnly)` and try again?